# segmentation fault (core dumped) using pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

When I build the code below, I get output

> Mystr
> segmentation fault (core dumped)

I guess strNULL and set function causeing error..
Am i guess wright???

I'm not sure what's wrong.
please tell me what's wrong and how to fix it.

I would appreciate if advice my coding style :D

**globalcall.c (global pointer declared)**

```
void *call = 0;
```

**string1.h (header file)**

```
typedef struct tag_string{
    char *str;
    unsigned int len;

    int (*compare)(struct tag_string *target);
    struct tag_string *(*set)(struct tag_string *target);
} string;

string *new_String(const char *str);
void delete_string(string *str);
```

**string.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string1.h"

extern string *call;

int _string_compare(string *target);
string *_string_set(string *target);

string *new_string(const char *str){
    string *ptr;
    int i = 0;

    ptr = (string *)malloc(sizeof(string));
    if(ptr == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    ptr->str = 0;
    ptr->len = 0;

    ptr->compare = _string_compare;
    ptr->set = _string_set;

    if(str){
        for(ptr->len = 0;str[ptr->len];ptr->len++);

        ptr->str = (char *)malloc(ptr->len + 1);

        if(ptr->str == 0){
            free(ptr);
            return 0;
        }
        for(i = 0;i<ptr->len + 1;i++){
            ptr->str[i] = str[i];
        }
    } else {
        ptr->str = (char *)malloc(1);
        ptr->str = 0;
    }

    return ptr;
}

void delete_string(string *str){
    if(str->str != 0){
        free(str->str);
        str->str = 0;
    }
    free(str);

    return;
}

int _string_compare(string *target){
    int i = 0;
    if(call->len != target->len){
        return 0;
    } else {
        for(i=0;i<call->len;i++){
            if(call->str[i] != target->str[i]){
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

string *_string_set(string *target){
    int i = 0;

    free(call->str);
    call->str = (char *)malloc(call->len+1);

    for(i = 0;i<call->len;i++){
        call->str[i] = target->str[i];
    }

    call->len = target->len;

    return call;
}
```

**Main file**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "string1.h"

extern void *call;

int main(void) {
    string *mystr = new_string("Mystr");
    string *strNULL = new_string(0);

    printf("%s\n",mystr->str);
    printf("%s\n",strNULL->str);

    if(strNULL->set(mystr)->compare(mystr)){
        printf("Compare : TRUE!");
    }

    printf("%s\n",mystr->str);
    printf("%s\n",strNULL->str);

    delete_string(mystr);
    delete_string(strNULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you **never** assign a value to the `call` variable.

And the variable is initialized to a null-pointer, hence any reference by `call->anything` triggers an Undefined Behavior.

Comment: yeam that and null null string in pointer is causing error XD
but last output is juse 'M'.. what happen?

Comment: @Luvid *Undefined* Behavior means just that: _undefined_. It is not defined what may happen. The program may work apparently correctly until it crashes minutes or weeks after; or it may terminate or crash immediately; it may return some weird results or hang up and not do anything. Considering 'what has happenned in an UB condition' is a pure waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite simple question, yet too tedious for the answers to seek the error in the code.

Here's my suggestion:
I assume you are running Linux Operating System
recompile your code with *-g* flag,
and use gdb to debug

or you can set ulimit -c to large enough, and run the code again to get core file and see how it goes wrong.

Comment: It's built in windows XD

Comment: @Luvid but run in UNIX like environment?

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit of a mess.  It is not clear why you are making it more complicated than it needs to be, but your segfault is here:

```
ptr->str = (char *)malloc(1);
ptr->str = 0;
```

I think what you mean is:

```
*(ptr->str) = 0;
```

Otherwise, you are creating a one-byte memory leak and setting the string to NULL, which will fail on:

```
printf("%s\n",strNULL->str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring in function `_string_set()`.

Problem no. 1:

You are dereferencing a pointer which is not initialized:

```
free(call->str);
```

Problem no. 2:

`call` is not initialized and you are trying to allocate memory to `str`:

```
call->str = (char *)malloc(call->len+1);
```

`call->len` is also **not initialized**.

Also, in `main()`, you are calling `compare()` for the `call` returned by `_string_set()` function but nowhere assigning the comparison function address to `call->compare`.

In short, your `_string_set()` function is full of [undefined behaviors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If I just make corrections in your `_string_set()` function, it will look like this:

```
string *_string_set(string *target){
    int i = 0;

    if (target == NULL)
            return NULL;

    if ((call != NULL) && (call->str != NULL)) {
            free(call->str);
            free(call);
    }

    call = malloc(sizeof(string));
    if (call == NULL)
            return NULL;

    call->len = target->len;
    call->str = malloc(call->len+1);
    if (call->str == NULL) {
            free(call);
            return NULL;
    }

    call->compare = target->compare;
    call->set = target->set;

    for(i = 0;i<call->len;i++){
            call->str[i] = target->str[i];
    }

    return call;
}
```

Note: These corrections in `_string_set()` is just to fix the segmentation fault in your program. There is a scope for improvement in your program.

I can see that in your program you are trying to set `strNULL` with values of `mystr`. For this, you need to pass the `strNULL` as well to `_string_set()` and in `_string_set()` make the appropriate changes.

**With the current implementation**, `_string_set()` will set the value of `call` member variable with `mystr` member variable values and your `_string_set()` returns `call`. The values of `mystr` will not reflect in `strNULL`.

---

Few suggestions for good coding practice:

1. Try not to use globals as much as possible.
2. Never cast `malloc` return. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
3. Before accessing a pointer, make sure that it is pointing to a valid memory.
4. After calling `malloc`, always check whether it has returned a valid memory or NULL.
5. Try to write a modular code.

Comment: Thanks very much!!
It was very helpful answer.